# Check multiple items on Navigation Bar

Tags: java, android, checkbox, colors, navigation

I have a BottomNavigationBar with 4 items and I want multiple items to be checkable. I know that this bar is used for navigating through activities but I want more than 1 item to be `chackable`

If not checkable at least change the text color or the icon color of items individually instead of changing them as a whole

Code

```
final BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigation.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(0, true, true);
        BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener =
                new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.vpn:

                            bottomNavigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.home).setVisible(false);
                            bottomNavigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.home).setChecked(true);
                            bottomNavigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.theme).setTitle("ON");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"VPN",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return true;

                            case R.id.incognito:
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Private",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return true;

                            case R.id.theme:
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Theme",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return true;
                            case R.id.home:

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Home",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                };
bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationItemSelectedListener);
```

**xml code**

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:background="@color/black"
android:theme="@style/BottomNavigationTheme"
app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"/>
```

**Style.xml**

```
<style name="BottomNavigationTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set by using following code -

```
bottomNavigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.my_menu_item_id1);
bottomNavigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.my_menu_item_id2);
bottomNavigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.my_menu_item_id3);
```

Or try below code to select multiple item -

```
bottomNavigation.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //here 5 is item count
                    MenuItem top = navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).getSubMenu().getItem(i);
                    if (top.isChecked()) top.setChecked(false);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can't select multiple Items with this.

Comment: did you tried with multiple statement? also let me know you want to select multiple item or just want to show multiple item selected?

Comment: I want to just show multiple items selected because im not using fragments. replaced fragments with my code so. Also this code make the last line's item selected. So basically once the second item is selected the first item gets unchecked

Comment: Yes i did. Any other option to highlight multiple items? Or atleast change the color of multiple item names

Comment: still not working. as per my knowledge android doesnt allow multiple items to be selected. so just help me with highlighting multiple items

Comment: any error? can you post your xml code of bottom navigation

Comment: Added XML. Sorry for the formatting. something wrong